# Appcelerator Studio 4.4 and XCode 6.1.1 - Cannot import provisioning Profile

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I created a new provisioning profile with new app ID for an application. I have created them in Apple Developer portal and when I do a reference in the accounts page in XCode 6, I can see the provisioning profiles.

But when I launch Appcelerator Studio and try to export it in AdHoc mode, I can see only the list of provisioning profiles prior to upgrade of Appcelerator Studio. The new provisioning profile is not displayed. If I try to browse and add it, then it given an error as it is either not correct or not proper.

Has anyone faced such issue and know how to resolve it?

Comment: Delete the old one and download a fresh copy of provisioning profile from apple developer portal and try again.

Comment: Have done it. Does not work. What I think might be the issue is some conflict with studio and cli. But I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium looks in the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory for all your provisioning profiles. This is where Xcode should be saving new provisioning profiles. You can manually downloading the provisioning profiles one-by-one and when you double click them in Finder, it will open them with Xcode in which Xcode will copy them into this directory.

I would go to that directory and sort by date modified and make sure your new provisioning profiles are in there. Second, I would verify the permissions of each provisioning profile file.

Lastly, open the Terminal and run `appc ti info -t ios` or `ti info -t ios` and verify that Titanium can see the provisioning profiles. Perhaps your provisioning profiles are expired? "ti info" will tell you if a provisioning profile is expired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I verified that the provisioning profiles are present in the location mentioned. The interesting point is that Studio cannot get the profile, but when I am trying to build it from command-line by the command appc ti build (adhoc) then it shows me the profile which I can select and build the application. Only when I am trybg ti build it from the Studio is when I cannot see the profile.

Comment: Also, when I try to run the commands (ti info -t ios with or without appc), I get an error pointing to 3.5.0.GA path with something with dynamic lookup. Is there any conflict with the node version?

Comment: That's strange that Studio doesn't show the provisioning profile, but the CLI does. Are you using the latest version of Studio? Also, what's the error you get when running "ti info -t ios"?

Comment: I am using Appcelerator Studio 4.4.0. On executing ti info -t ios I am getting the error as:

 |dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
  Referenced from: /Users/soumya/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/out/node_ios_device_v14.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found:
  Referenced from: /Users/soumya/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/out/node_ios_device_v14.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: While writing the commentwhat caught my attention was that 3.5.0.GA is being referred. I think we need to change it to 5.1.2.GA to default. I have not tried it though.